# Display six month data using given date MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i need help for mySQL query. I want to display previous six months based on given firstDate and endDate. Both are from my $_GET php. 
What i want is, to display six months including the months that is empty.
Below is my current query.

```
SELECT m.monthNo as monthGroup, count(f.id) AS bilangan from monthEmpty m 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id,month, code FROM survey ) f 
ON DATE_FORMAT(f.month, '%c') = m.monthNo 
WHERE (month between DATE_SUB('2014-08-01', interval 5 month) and '2014-08-31') AND code = '001' 
group by monthGroup
```

For my monthEmpty, i have one column which is monthNo where the values is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 and 12.
And for survey table, i have id of responden,month with format of YYYY-MM-DD and code is responden faculty.
Currently my query still display only months that have value.
Appreciate if someone can figure out what to add to make empty months also display. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.monthNo AS monthGroup, COUNT( f.id ) AS bilangan
FROM monthEmpty m
JOIN (

SELECT id, 
MONTH , code
FROM survey
)f ON DATE_FORMAT( f.month,  '%c' ) = m.monthNo
AND (

MONTH BETWEEN DATE_SUB(  '2014-08-01', INTERVAL 5 
MONTH ) 
AND  '2014-08-31'
)
AND code =  '001'
GROUP BY monthGroup
```

Use this query, you need to combine where caluse with left join

Comment: it now display all months even empty. However, may i know how to display previous six months from given date? (exp:'2014-08-01'). So it will display aug,july,june,may,apr,mac.

Comment: this query display data between 2014-03-01 and 2014-08-31

Comment: Here is new query, SELECT m.monthNo AS monthGroup, COUNT( f.id ) AS bilangan
FROM monthEmpty m
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id, monthSurvey , code FROM survey) f 
ON DATE_FORMAT( f.monthSurvey,  '%c' ) = m.monthNo
AND (f.monthSurvey BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2014-08-01', INTERVAL 5 MONTH ) AND  '2014-08-31')
AND code =  '001'
GROUP BY monthGroup.. as i follow ur query.
I'm not sure if i miss something because it still display 1 till 12 when it should be display 3 till 8 only...

Comment: Please, confirm you want all 1 to 12 data (with 0 value in between rantge) or you want only between range value withour 0 value

Comment: i apologize if it is confusing. I'm trying to display only previous six month using the date given(exp:'2014-08-01'). Therefore my expected result should display from Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul and Aug regardless it have value or not. Thats why i create another fake table which is monthEmpty.
Currently as i follow query above,it display all 12 based on my monthEmpty table. Did i use the correct query and did i use monthEmpty table correctly?